# Necesito imprimir varias querys en columnas diferentes en una tabla de html

Tags: php, html, ms-access, odbc

Tengo una tabla algo grande y para cada columna necesito una query diferente, el problema es que no consigo que me imprima los datos en la columna de la derecha siguiente;

```
$connect = odbc_connect("proyecto", "usuario", "contrasena");
print ("Fecha de Inicio: $newDate1  Fecha Final: $newDate2");
# query the datos table giving group of vendedor and count of vendedor
$query = "SELECT  datos.vendedor, count (vendedor)                 
FROM datos where datos.fecha_reg >= #$newDate1# and datos.fecha_reg  <= 
#$newDate2#
 GROUP BY vendedor
 ORDER BY vendedor";

# perform the query
$result = odbc_exec($connect, $query);

# fetch the data from the database
while(odbc_fetch_row($result)){
$s1 = odbc_result($result, 1);
$s2 = odbc_result($result, 2);
print("<tr><th>$s1</th><th> $s2 </th></tr>");
}
# connect to a DSN "mydb" with a user and password 
$connect2 = odbc_connect("proyecto", "usuario", "contrasena");
$query2 = "SELECT  datos.modelo, count (modelo)                 
 FROM datos where datos.fecha_reg >= #$newDate1# and datos.fecha_reg  <= 
 #$newDate2#
 GROUP BY modelo
 ORDER BY modelo";
 # perform the query2
$result2 = odbc_exec($connect2, $query2);
# fetch the data from the database
while(odbc_fetch_row($result2)){
  $x1 = odbc_result($result2, 1);
  $x2 = odbc_result($result2, 2);
  print("<tr><th><th><th>$x1</th><th> $x2 </th></th></th></tr>");
}
# close the connection
odbc_close($connect);  
odbc_close($connect2);
```

Este código es de solo 2 consultas, necesito hacer varias, pero el resultado de la segunda consulta lo imprime abajo en lugar de al lado de las primeras dos columnas.

Answer (score 1):

La etiqueta [`<tr>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Elemento/tr) indica que el contenido es una fila de tabla (***T**able **R**ow* en inglés). Los resultados de ambas consultas se escriben en sus propias filas (`<tr>...</tr>`) y por eso se muestran una encima de la otra.

Si quieres que las celdas que obtienes en la segunda consulta aparezcan en la misma fila que las celdas que imprimes en la primera consulta, lo que deberías hacer es ponerlas todos dentro del mismo `<tr>`. Es decir, no hagas `</tr>` en el primer `print` y tampoco hagas `<tr>` en el segundo `print`.

Algo como esto (sólo el código relacionado y he aprovechado para quitar `th` que sobraban):

```
...

# fetch the data from the database
while(odbc_fetch_row($result)){
$s1 = odbc_result($result, 1);
$s2 = odbc_result($result, 2);
  print("<tr><th>$s1</th><th> $s2 </th>");
}

...

# fetch the data from the database
while(odbc_fetch_row($result2)){
  $x1 = odbc_result($result2, 1);
  $x2 = odbc_result($result2, 2);
  print("<th>$x1</th><th> $x2 </th></tr>");
}

...
```

Comment: Aunque esto se basa en que sólo obtienes un registro en cada una de las consultas. Si obtuvieses más, lo que querrías hacer es escribir `<tr>` al principio, realizar la consulta, escribir los datos con `print` (sólo los `<td>` y `<th>`), realizar la siguiente consulta, escribir los datos con `print` (sólo los `<td>` y `<th>`), y cerrar escribiendon `</tr>`